# Counting keywords in dict

Tags: dictionary, count

I have searched for this but I'm not able to find anything similar to this specific situation:

I have a dict:

```
nominees = {1931: ['Larry Holmes', 'Jason Russell'],
             1932: ['Frank Smith', 'Larry Holmes', 'Jason Russell']}
```

I'm trying to create a new dict that has the name of each nominee as key, with an int value of how many times they were nominated. Something like this:

```
nom_count_dict = {'Larry Holmes': 2, 'Jason Russell': 2, 'Frank Smith': 1}
```

The code that I have so far is wrong. Here is what I have so far:

```
for year, noms in nominated.items():
    for nominee in noms:
        if nominee not in nom_count_dict:
            nom_count_dict.update({nominee: 1})
        elif nominee in nom_count_dict:
            nom_count_dict.update({nominee: len(nom_count_dict.keys())})
```

This is counting the number of total keys within the new dict and adding it onto the value. I know the issue lies here: `len(nom_count_dict.keys())` but I can't figure out what to put in len(). Or maybe I shouldn't even be using len()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your elif clause i.e when you encounter a nominee name, just increment the present nominee count by 1. So your elif clause will look like below

```
nom_count_dict.update({nominee: nom_count_dict[nominee]+1})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the answer, and also for the explanation!